# Using trickle with Git

Tags: git, bandwidth-throttling, trickle

I would like to throttle a simple git pull using [trickle](http://monkey.org/~marius/trickle/trickle.1.txt). This seems like it should be easy: `trickle -d 100 git pull`, but when git shows its bandwidth rate, it still hovers around 3.3 MiB/s for me, much greater than the supposed maximum of 1000 KB/s.

I am discouraged by the fact that it looks like trickle hasn't been updated in 8 years, but I am hoping I can still resolve this problem.

Other random info that may prove helpful:

- Fedora 20
- `trickle -V`: `trickle: version 1.07`
- `git --version`: `git version 1.9.0`
- I also use `hub`, but I have tried with and without hub. I don't see any difference.
- I use zsh.
- `ip addr`:

`1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: em1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:2e:5f:86:4b:8b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.142/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic em1
       valid_lft 64050sec preferred_lft 64050sec
    inet6 2601:d:b700:679:a2e:5fff:fe86:4b8b/64 scope global noprefixroute dynamic 
       valid_lft 216580sec preferred_lft 216580sec
    inet6 fe80::a2e:5fff:fe86:4b8b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4c:80:93:a0:d7:14 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`

Of course, I am more than happy to provide any other information. Thank you.

Comment: What is trickle? In general, it is a good idea to add links to libraries and tools that aren't necessarily well known. As it stands, this looks like a question for [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or possibly [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 9):

Just tried it like this, and it worked - at least with a git clone, give it a shot.

Fedora 20 | trickle 1.07 | git 1.9.3

```
trickle -sd 100 git clone
```

And the `-s` stands for:

```
-s           Run trickle in standalone mode independent of trickled
```

Answer (score 1):

fyi Trickle wont work with git protocol because trickle can only [limit tcp connections](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/control-your-bandwidth-trickle).  That's why it works for http

Answer (score 0):

I found on freebsd that trickle didn't work cloning via the git protocol, but when did when cloning via HTTPS

FreeBSD 10.2-RELEASE | git 2.4.5 | trickle 1.07

Comment: Welcome to SO! This isn't a terribly clear answer. Try to provide more explanation to your answers. And maybe examples. See [How to answer page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for help in improving your answer.