# Is there a way to limit git bandwith during a huge "repo clone"?

Tags: git

I want to clone different big GIT repos (like Linux kernel or Android sources) but as they are huge (I know I can limit the size with `--depth`, but it's not the idea here) I will totally use the home bandwith (450kbps) for days.

I tried the tool `trickle` and even if it works well on a `wget` example, it does not work for `git clone`.

How do you limit the bandiwth of a git clone command ?

Thanks !

Comment: There are a few hints here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480149/using-trickle-with-git

Comment: I've seen this, but it does not work. There is not "trick". The -s option simply disable a warning message.

Comment: The `-s` option works for me. I did `trickle -s -u 200 -d 200 git clone ssh://<user>@<host>/<path to repo>.git` and Git reports the download going at about 200 KB/s.

Comment: @ntc2 Could you please post your comment as an answer? `echo "alias git='trickle -s -d 4096 -u 1536 /usr/bin/git'" >> ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 8):

You can use `trickle` directly like this

```
trickle -s -u 200 -d 200 git clone ssh://<user>@<host>/<path to repo>.git
```

In that example the up and down bandwidth is limited to 200kB/s, but you can adjust to your needs.

Answer (score 3):

I would think you want `trickle` to act on the underlying `ssh` command used by `git` (assuming ssh is the underlying protocol for the URL), so something along the lines of this might work (untested - substitute the applicable values for your environment):

```
$ (echo '#!/bin/sh'; echo 'trickle -s -d 100 -u 100 ssh "$@"') > $HOME/bin/trickle-ssh.sh
$ chmod a+rx $HOME/bin/trickle-ssh.sh
$ export GIT_SSH=$HOME/bin/trickle-ssh.sh

$ git clone ...
```

Comment: Thanks but it still not work. If I refer to `man git` GIT_SSH is not used by "git clone". It is only used by "fetch" and "push".
By the way, as I am using git:// protocol, I'm not sure it would work in any way.

Comment: The `GIT_SSH` setting is definitely used by `git clone`s that happen over SSH. The problem with the above is probably that the `$HOME/bin/trickle-ssh.sh` script is buggy: it throws away the SSH arguments! I'll edit the answer and fix it ...